# Why did my log output three lines?

Tags: python

I want the correct output.

Why did my log output three lines?

my code is:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
#LOG
import time

def log_info(log):
    LOG_FILENAME='log'
    # Set up a specific logger with our desired output level
    my_logger = logging.getLogger('log')
    my_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    # Add the log message handler to the logger
    handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILENAME,
                maxBytes=1048576,
                backupCount=5,
               )
    my_logger.addHandler(handler)
    # Log some messages
    my_logger.info(log)

def test(log):
    log_info(log=log)

for i in range(2):
    print i
    a = "1111111111111"
    b = test(a)
```

my result:

```
1111111111111
1111111111111
1111111111111
```

I was expecting this:

```
1111111111111
1111111111111
```

Comment: What is the correct output?

Comment: Your code initalize the log on every call, instead of writing to it.

Comment: the correct result is two lines  not three lines@quamrana

Comment: put print outside for loop?????@VanPeer

Comment: @Vinny How should I write?

Comment: Check out Python log documentations. Basically you initalize it once, and then `logger.info('msg')` for every event

Comment: The problem is that each time you call `log_info`, you are calling `addHandler`.  So the first time it's called, you add the first handler, and the text gets logged once.  The second time, you add a second handler, so now everything gets logged twice.  Split the function into (a) a function that initializes the handler, and (b) a function that logs a new message.  Call (a) once, and only once.  After that, call (b) every time you want to log a new message (all it should do is call `my_logger.info`).

Comment: There are a lot of logs in my project. I mostly want to set the size of the log file, and then store the log. Log duplication is found at tail -f log. The question I'm asking is just one example

Comment: @TomKarzes: That was an answer! You should post it as such.

Comment: I'll try@TomKarzes

Comment: @quamrana Ok, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each time you call `log_info`, you are calling `addHandler`. So the first time it's called, you add the first handler, and the text gets logged once. The second time, you add a second handler, so now everything gets logged twice.

Split the function into (a) a function that initializes the handler, and (b) a function that logs a new message. Call (a) once, and only once. After that, call (b) every time you want to log a new message (all it should do is call `my_logger.info`).

Answer (score 0):

So, @TomKarzes is instructing you to write your code like this:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

def initialise_log():
    LOG_FILENAME = 'log'
    # Set up a specific logger with our desired output level
    my_logger = logging.getLogger('log')
    my_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    # Add the log message handler to the logger
    handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILENAME,
                maxBytes=1048576,
                backupCount=5,
               )
    my_logger.addHandler(handler)
    return my_logger

def test(log):
    # Log some messages
    my_logger.info(log)

my_logger = initialise_log()

for i in range(2):
    print i
    a = "1111111111111"
    b = test(a)
```